# Find common factor to convert list of floats to list of integers

Tags: python, floating-point

I have a list of floats which comes from some other function.
What I know is that in ideal world there exist a common factor
which can be used to multiply each term to obtain list of integers.
There could be some small numerical noise (~1e-14).

So for example

```
[2.3333333333333335, 4.666666666666667, 1.0, 1.6666666666666667]
```

here each term can by multiplied by 3 to obtain

```
[7.0, 14.0, 3.0, 5.0]
```

How can I find this term? We can assume integer solution exists.

Any helpful comments will be appreciated

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: tried divide by greatest common divisor for a list. it works sometimes but often goes wild

Comment: What is the gdc for non-integer numbers?

Comment: The precision of `float`s will make this difficult to do in general, e.g. `2.333...35 * 3` is not `7`.

Comment: that's the catch. the gcd works for non-integer numbers if they are integers divided by some common factor but only if they divide nicely, say 5/2 = 2.5 but not 2/3 = 0.6(6)

Comment: In this case I would assume that you need to set some threshold accuracy beyond which decimals are neglected.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that; e.g. for nice fractions (2.50..01) to compute gcd you need to set some threshold but it still fails for 2/3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python's [Fraction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) type can convert floating points to rationals with denominators under 1000000, and then you can find the lowest common denominator.

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> a = [2.3333333333333335, 4.666666666666667, 1.0, 1.6666666666666667]
>>> [Fraction(x).limit_denominator() for x in a]
[Fraction(7, 3), Fraction(14, 3), Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(5, 3)]
```

A straightforward way to find the least common multiple using the [math.gcd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) function:

```
>>> denoms = [3,3,1,2]
>>> functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a*b//math.gcd(a,b), denoms)
6
```

Comment: You're half-way there... this doesn't guarantee a *common* factor.

Comment: Very nice trick! But in theory, we should first guess the denominator limit (the default is 1000000).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The brute force solution. Still looking for something more universal...

```
def find_int(arr):
    test = False
    epsilon = 1e-15
    maxint = 1000
    for i in range(2, maxint, 1):
        for item in arr:
            if abs(i*item-round(i*item)) < epsilon:
                test = True
            else:
                test = False
                break
        if test:
            print i
            return [int(round(i*item)) for item in arr]
    print "Could not find one"
    return arr
```

Comment: Beware, `abs(x - int(x))` is not a good test! Think of 0.999999999: it is *close* to 1 but `int(0.999999999)` is 0...

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. Will change it to round()