# strange results when converting floating point numbers to fractions using MASS::fractions in R

Tags: r, math, primes

I am trying to do something similar to what is discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587875/find-common-factor-to-convert-list-of-floats-to-list-of-integers), but in R rather than Python.

However:

```
require(MASS)
fractions(0.723618,max.denominator = 1000000)
#[1] 89/123
```

This seems to indicate that floating point number 0.723618 is better described by fraction 89/123 than by 361809/500000, which does not seem correct to me.

Even more puzzling:

```
fractions(0.7236,max.denominator = 100000000000)
#[1] 89/123
```

Surely it would be better to write 0.7236 as 1809/5000, wouldn't it?

**Do you know why this happens? Do you think it's 'normal'?**

For context: I'm asking because this causes issues when trying to find a common denominator <= 1000000 for a vector of floating point numbers, which one may want to use to convert them to a vector of integers with a specified minimal number of significant digits.
The appearance of these weird denominators makes the LCM of the vector of denominators very large.

---

**EDIT** : follow-up from Jon Spring's suggestion

```
for (i in 1:18) (print(fractions(0.723618,cycles=i)))
#[1] 1
#[1] 2/3
#[1] 3/4
#[1] 5/7
#[1] 8/11
#[1] 13/18
#[1] 21/29
#[1] 34/47
#[1] 55/76
#[1] 89/123
#[1] 144/199
#[1] 40121/55445
#[1] 40265/55644
#[1] 80386/111089
#[1] 281423/388911
#[1] 361809/5e+05
#[1] 361809/5e+05
#[1] 361809/5e+05
```

However:

```
fractions(0.3333,cycles=1)
#[1] 1/3
fractions(0.3333,cycles=10)
#[1] 1/3
fractions(0.3333,cycles=100)
#[1] 1/3
fractions(0.3333,cycles=100,max.denominator = 1000)
#[1] 1/3
fractions(0.3333,cycles=100,max.denominator = 10000)
#[1] 3333/10000
```

So it seems that indeed, the two parameters `max.denominator` and `cycles` somehow determine how large the denominator can become, but at first sight the relationship does not look very straightforward.

Comment: Adjust the `cycles` parameter, which has default of 10. It looks like that's the main way of controlling the granularity of the approximation; max.denominator is rather an "early termination criterion" that doesn't totally control the output.

Comment: More in the help: `?fractions`

Comment: Thank you Jon! It is indeed interesting how the two parameters influence the result. I will make an edit to the OP.

Comment: I know it's very annoying when function does something else than promised but there is always a workaround. Please have a look at one of these cases in my answer and let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you Vitali, your function below seems indeed to do the trick! I'll need some time to get my head around it. For the more general problem that I'm trying to address, however, I see now that I am still struggling with weird denominators. It is not guaranteed that fractions will work as I want even if I manage to limit the denominator size. It can be < 1e6 but still a prime. I will make a new post on that subject, otherwise I'm sure the 'off topic' police will be on my case in no time.

Comment: Just a brief note: numbers::ratFarey seems to provide the required fractions while limiting the denominator size; contFrac does a similar job, too, but it inexplicably fails for some numbers. As for how to handle an arbitrary list of floating point numbers, my current idea is to use ratFarey to find all denominators, with n = 1.e6, then tabulate them, reduce to unique, sort by descending frequency, and construct the overall factor iteratively by making the LCM of the denominators that increase the number of integers at each step. I'll try it out first and post it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of considering only max.denominator and disregarding `cycles` by assigning it to a big number:

```
library(purrr)

max.denominator = 1000000
decimal_num <- 0.723618
max_cycles <- 1000
do_not_know_cycles <- map(1:max_cycles,
                            function(x) {
                              try <- fractions(decimal_num,cycles = x,
                                               max.denominator = max.denominator)
                              nom_denom <- strsplit(attr(try,"fracs"),"/")
                              int_denom <- nom_denom[[1]][2]
                              list_return <- list(try,int_denom)
                              }) 
binded_ <- do_not_know_cycles %>% 
  do.call(rbind,.)

cc <- max.denominator - as.numeric(binded_[,2])
indx <- which.min(cc[cc>=0])
out <- do_not_know_cycles[[indx]][1]
out
```

As said, you need only to put `max_cycles` big enough and specify `max.denominator` which will bring the max-denominator fraction for a given decimal.

Here are the outputs of `0.723618` for max.denominators: 1000000,100000,100

```
> out
[[1]]
[1] 361809/5e+05

> out
[[1]]
[1] 40265/55644

> out
[[1]]
[1] 55/76
```